# Converting a LibreOffice Impress slideshow so that it will run on my wife's blog

Tags: libreoffice, slideshow, blog

My wife is an artist and she made a slideshow at my suggestion in Impress.  After spending a Jillion hours learning how to make it work and the whole learning curve thing she was finally satisfied with the results. At my suggestion she exported it as an HTML and tried to post it on her EBlog page. It didn't work. What she has googled says that she has to convert the slide show to a .SWF that seems strange to me. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

`.swf` is flash and can be used to embed video's.

To export the presentation as a Flash file:

- File > Export.
- Under File Format, choose Macromedia Flash (SWF) (.swf) and click Save.